# Does @get_headers download the full file or just the metadata?

Tags: php

I have download files on my website that are using @get_headers to check if the files exist and to retrieve the Content-Length (file size) metadata. I recently moved by download files to my CDN because I noticed a 50% speed increase in downloads but after the move I've noticed a huge increase in my CDN usage from 5GB to 120GB+ per month after moving the files.

I was wondering does @get_headers download the full file to retrieve the metadata or does it grab the metadata without downloading the full file?

If @get_headers does download the full file to retrieve metadata is there another solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses a GET, which is what you're calling a "full file".  What you want to do is use a HEAD request.  This is [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) in a comment on the PHP page for the function:

```
<?php
// By default get_headers uses a GET request to fetch the headers. If you
// want to send a HEAD request instead, you can do so using a stream context:
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'HEAD'
        )
    )
);
$headers = get_headers('http://example.com');
```

Comment: Will this only effect "get_headers" functions?

Comment: No.  It will affect every subsequent call that also uses the default stream context.  You can set it back to GET afterwards if you like.

Comment: If I set this up in a function to request a HEAD will it only request HEADs in the function or will it change things globally in my php file?

Comment: It is altering the php-wide default stream context.  Every php function that subsequently uses that context will also be affected until that particular php process dies.